# Fragment "disappears" after opening new fragment and then coming back

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is kind of hard to explain so I took screenshots of my problem.

So this is my MainActivity.java

[image]

I open the navigation drawer and click on Milestones which will bring me to Milestones.java

[image]

Here I am at Milestones.java fragment...

[image]

working fine for now...

[image]

Just how I want it to look.

[image]

But when we leave Milestones and go anywhere else and come back it will be messed up. So I will go to Kick Counter.

[image]

Here I am in my KickCounter.java fragment

[image]

Open navigation drawer and going back to Milestones...

[image]

So right now I have fragment Months0Through6 open with Milestones fragment. Some times Months0Through6 and Month12Plus fragments does not show up right away after coming back some times it does. What is always messed up at this point is the Months6Through12 fragment will never display again unless you restart the app. Also swapping between the three fragments is laggy after coming back but never on first view.

[image]

Here it is. Where did it go?

[image]

[image]

youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yMYcluvqbs

Get Source Here: https://github.com/delaroy/RecyclerViewFragment

I got my code from this youtube video which is almost exactly identical but his MainActivity (which I made into my Milestones fragment) is an activity whereas I used a fragment so I was thinking that might have something to do with my problem.

Milestones.java

```
public class Milestones extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Milestones() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment Milestones.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Milestones newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Milestones fragment = new Milestones();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_milestones, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                                                 //dont know if this will work
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    for(int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++){
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

// not boiler plate
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

// probably just adding extra menu dont need it
/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
*/

//not boilerplate
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.action_settings){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

//not boilerplate
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"0-6 Months", "6-12 Months", "12+ Months"};
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Months0Through6();
            case 1:
                return new Months6Through12();
            case 2:
                return new Months12Plus();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position){
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

MilestonesAdapter.java

```
public class MilestonesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MilestonesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private String[] mDataset;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public MyViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

    }

}

public MilestonesAdapter(String[] myDataset){
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MilestonesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDataset.length; }
```

Just posting Months0Through6.java because the other two are exactly the same just different strings.

```
public class Months0Through6 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public Months0Through6() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    MilestonesAdapter adapter = new MilestonesAdapter(new String[]{"Month 0 stuff", "Example Two", "Example Three", "Example Four", "Example Five" , "Example Six" , "Example Seven"});
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements KickCounter.OnFragmentInteractionListener, MommyMetrics.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Milestones.OnFragmentInteractionListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Intent shareIntent;
String sharetext = "Hey check out mommy-info here at http://www.mommy-info.com";
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Connects to www.mommy-info.com
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_ID);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mommy-info.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //back button in navigation drawer logic
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    //back button in webView logic
    else if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
        myWebView.goBack();
    }
    else if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.kick_counter_ID) {

        KickCounter kickCounter = new KickCounter();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.full_screen_ID, kickCounter).addToBackStack(null).commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_mommy_metrics) {

        MommyMetrics mommyMetrics = new MommyMetrics();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.full_screen_ID, mommyMetrics).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_milestones) {

        Milestones milestones = new Milestones();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.full_screen_ID, milestones).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my app");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharetext);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share via"));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fragments you need to use getChildFragmentManager(), You are using same Fragment manager in the fragments as in Activity. Hope this will help

Comment: Exactly what it was. Thank you!